# Keep cell content on one page

Tags: java, itext

I have a table, with one column. Each cell contains a paragraph.

How can I stop paragraphs from splitting across two pages?

```
PdfPtable table = new PdfPTable(1);

//report must be printed as compat as possible
table.setSplitLate(false);

//I can't set keep together, because table can be larger than page size
//table.setKeepTogether(true);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    //Random text. Can contain ~400 chars.
    String text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa sssssssssssss ddddddddddd ffffffffff";
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text);

    //That instruction does not work. I don't know why, may be because paragraph printed in cell.
    p.setKeepTogether(true);

    table.addCell(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
table.setSplitLate(false);
```

into

```
table.setSplitLate(true);
```

This way, your cell will not be split unless the complete cell doesn't fit on a single page.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not resolve my problem. So, paragraph.setKeepTogether(true); will no work in this case?

Comment: You should remove the line `paragraph.setKeepTogether(true);` and explain *"this does not resolve my problem."* You have one paragraph for each cell, hence `table.setSplitLate(true);` will keep the paragraph together, which is what you're asking, isn't it? If not, I fear that I don't understand your question (nor do many other developers).

Comment: I have a SectionTable extends PdfPTable that override some rendering functions (borders at left and right and bottom of table, and underline border not for all table width for each cell), and contain only one column). I have two instances of SectionTable, each of them contain a lot of small paragraphes. First instance contain second instance as last cell. I need to keep each paragraph on one page, but each table must be situated compat as it possible. So, I think, better solution will be create a wrapper - SectionTable with PdfPtable and Section Table in it.

Comment: Your comment is not clear. If you want a border for the complete table rather than for the individual cells, you should use a table event. It seems that you are creating a problem by complicating things. These complications are hard to understand for outsiders. There's a saying by Martin Golding: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live."